# Необходимо скопировать записи с одной таблицу в другую идентичную. Автоинкремента по ключу нет, как избежать повторения ключа?

Tags: c#, sql

Есть основная (первая) таблица и дополнительная (вторая), в которую иногда делаются копии записей из первой. По структуре они идентичны, только во второй таблице отключен автоинкремент по столбцу Код - первичный ключ, а в первой включен. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при копировании данных из первой таблицы во вторую избегалось повторение Код`а.

Запрос:

```
Insert into Нагр2(Код, Столбец2, Столбец3...)
Select Код, Столбец2, Столбец3... From Нагр1
Where Нагр1.СтолбецN = '...'
```

Думал сделать (MAX(Код) + 1) as Код, но не понял куда вставить. Как можно доработать запрос, чтобы записи копировались и не возникало конфликтов с кодом?

Comment: Сделать во второй таблице ключом поле, куда класть новый GUID и не париться. Что за база то? И вообще есть возможность модифицировать вторую таблицу?

Comment: А, стоп, если там копии, то копируйте просто те записи из таблицы1, которых нет в таблице2 (по ключу и проверяйте наличие). Если в первой таблице ключи не повторяются, то и во втрой не будут.

Answer (score 0):

Можете просто добавлять во вторую таблицу те записи из первой таблицы, которых там ещё нет. По ключу и проверяйте их наличие. Если в первой ключи не пересекаются, то и во второй это поле не пересечётся.

```
Insert into Нагр2(Код, Столбец2, Столбец3...)
Select Код, Столбец2, Столбец3... From Нагр1
where Нагр2.Код not in (select Код from Нагр1)
```

Comment: Дело в том, что надо добавлять именно все записи.

Comment: @ViktorBezrukov А, ладно. Да я могу полно вариантов придумать, но нужна доп. инфа. Какого вида этот Код - число? В каких пределах? Например, если оно не знаю там заведомо меньше 100000, то можно делать как бы "номер сессии" и добавлять его, умножив на 100000 к коду из таблицы1. Или вообще сделать новое поле куда писать номер сессии, если можно с Код-а в таблице2 убрать первичный ключ.

Comment: Код - число, любое может встретиться. Размер поля - 4 байта. Добавлять новые поля в таблицу нельзя. Вот как раз вопрос: как добавлять в таблицу2 новые записи и делать манипуляции с Кодом в одном запросе?